# Cant load images dynamically imported with webpack-image-loader and called from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, image, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to load some images dynamically from a JSON file, I'm using webpack-image-loader and react.

I used several pngs for this purpose, and it worked when I put the variable name inside the curly braces:

`import gratuita from 'images/gift-50.png';`

`<img src={gratuita} className="pool-icons"/>`

But when I try to do it with the help of a JSON file the problems arrived.

I am importing my images (pngs) as follow, with some help of webpack-image-loader as shown before:

`import Baseball from 'images/BaseballBall-50.png';`

Then i am calling my image and taking a JSON property to call the right file shown in the example below:

`<img src={sport.name} className="pool-icons"/>`

The JSON file has the next data structure:

```
"sport": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Baseball"
      },
```

Then, when the img is called, the image don't show up, and the src file didn't parse the variable as the src route, instead, it just got the name of the variable as shown here:
[the image don't show up,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC3Uv.png)

I've tried with eval() but it didn't work, it throws me this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Baseball is not defined
at eval (eval at DisplaySport (eval at <anonymous> (output.js:5211)), <anonymous>:1:1)
at DisplaySport (eval at <anonymous> (output.js:5211), <anonymous>:247:13)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (output.js:7605), <anonymous>:306:16)
at measureLifeCyclePerf (eval at <anonymous> (output.js:7605), <anonymous>:75:12)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (eval at <anonymous> (output.js:7605), <anonymous>:305:14)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (eval at <anonymous> (output.js:7605), <anonymous>:280:21)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (output.js:7605), <anonymous>:188:21)
at Object.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (output.js:1396), <anonymous>:46:35)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (eval at <anonymous> (output.js:7917), <anonymous>:238:44)
at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (eval at <anonymous> (output.js:7629), <anonymous>:697:32)
```

Thanks in advance, I'm stuck in this part and it would be nice some help of the community.

Comment: Shouldn't you give `src` of image instead name of `sport`

Comment: That's the issue, the src PATH is within a variable named as the sport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a condition to check if name of sport matches with Baseball,

```js
const Baseball = "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/20/56/e1/2056e16bbc03d5eb41b4761356a8411b.jpg"

const sport={
  id: "1",
  name: "Baseball"
}

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const name = sport.name
    return(
      <div>
        {sport.name === "Baseball" && <img src={Baseball} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: That's sounds fair, i have to built a switch statement, or something similar to control the different variables because there are 8 types of sports.

Comment: I've finally solved it with a switch statement that catch every sport.name, is more code to write, but it works just fine. Thanks